# How to check if Async Task is already running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that needs to do an intensive database operation on start up. The app holds a local copy of the contacts on the phone and synchronizes with the android contact database on startup.

If a user starts the app, an Async Task is started that does the database synch in the background. If the user closes the app, the operation continues running which is fine. However if the user opens the app again, the Async Task is started and an error is produced.

Is there anyway of checking if the Task is already running from a different instance of the app?

Comment: What is the error that is produced? My AsyncTask just hangs on preExecute so I'm wondering if it's related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should check the concept of `Application` in `Android`. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

In fact there is no such thing as

> different instance of the app

. The `Application` is always the same for all your `Activities/Services.`
That means that you'd left the `Activity` and opened it again, 2 cases are possible:

1. The system already killed your application. In this case `AsyncTask` is dead already and it's safe to start a new one
2. The `Application` was still alive, so `AsyncTask` possibly still running.

In 2nd case I will recommend to use some static variables, pointing to this `AsyncTask` or it's state. If your app was still alive when 2nd time opened - all static references will be still valid, so you can successfully operate.

PS: By the way, in current approach be aware that your application can be terminated by the system at any time. So `AsyncTask` can be interrupted in any moment. It it's not ok for you - please check `IntentServices` - components, specially designed for background-operation purpose. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Good luck!

Comment: Static variable at application level seems to be the way.Thanks

Answer (score 97):

Use [`getStatus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) to get the status of your `AsyncTask`. If status is [`AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) then your task is running.

**EDIT:** you should reconsider your implementation and hold the `AsyncTask` probably in a `Service` or `IntentService` to fetch your data from the web.

Comment: calling getStatus() resulted in Null Pointer Exception, but I could see the async task still running..

Comment: Did you use something like :
`(yourtask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)` ?

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: asynctask with intent service is not required as intent service already have worker thread

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to handle this problem with some sort of Singleton pattern.
Hope it helps.

```
// fill the places database from a JSON object
public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> {

    Activity mContext = null;
    static AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> myAsyncTaskInstance = null; 

    // Private Constructor: can't be called from outside this class
    private myAsyncTask(Activity iContext) {
        mContext = iContext; 
    }

    public static AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> getInstance(Activity iContext) {
        // if the current async task is already running, return null: no new async task 
        // shall be created if an instance is already running
        if (myAsyncTaskInstance != null && myAsyncTaskInstance.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
            // it can be running but cancelled, in that case, return a new instance
            if (myAsyncTaskInstance.isCancelled()) {
                myAsyncTaskInstance = new myAsyncTask(iContext);
            } else {
                // display a toast to say "try later"
                Toast.makeText(iContext, "A task is already running, try later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

                return null;
            }
        }

        //if the current async task is pending, it can be executed return this instance
        if (myAsyncTaskInstance != null && myAsyncTaskInstance.getStatus() == Status.PENDING) {
            return myAsyncTaskInstance;
        }

        //if the current async task is finished, it can't be executed another time, so return a new instance
        if (myAsyncTaskInstance != null && myAsyncTaskInstance.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED) {
            myAsyncTaskInstance = new myAsyncTask(iContext);
        }


        // if the current async task is null, create a new instance
        if (myAsyncTaskInstance == null) {
            myAsyncTaskInstance = new myAsyncTask(iContext);
        }
        // return the current instance
        return myAsyncTaskInstance;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... iUnUsed) {
        // ...
    }
}
```