# Know if AsyncTask is Running

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, task

I have an activity which gets called every time a Call is ended. This activity has below AsyncTask.

```
UploadRecordings uploadRecordings = new UploadRecordings();
uploadRecordings.execute(context);
```

Now when I get many Calls one after another, everytime new AysncTask is created. But Android limits the number of AsyncTask to 5. So problem is I want to check if a AsyncTask is already running, and if found running, don't create a new AsyncTask. I want to create a new AsyncTask if there is no AsyncTask running.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: For Simple Solution create boolean value and set after completion of asynctask in onPostexecute(). You can use simple interface class for this.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`getStatus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus()) to get the status of your `AsyncTask`. If status is [`AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) then your task is running.

check this way

```
if(uploadRecordings.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
    // My AsyncTask is currently doing work in doInBackground()
}
```

For More Detail Read : [Android, AsyncTask, check status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588584/android-asynctask-check-status)

Comment: But where should I write this code. New object of UploadRecordings is created everytime.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[getStatus ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29)**

> Returns the current status of this task.

```
if(YourAsyncTaskOBJ.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
    {
      // AsyncTask Running  
    }
```

Read **[How to check if Async Task is already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236899/how-to-check-if-async-task-is-already-running)**

Comment: I need to know where should I write this code as uploadRecording is created everytime.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Declare global and checking

Comment: Doesn't the variable gets intialized as the activity is called everytime call is ended.

Answer (score 1):

Override `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`, which is executed whenever a call is completed. Set some flags in `onPostExecute()` and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Dealing with AsyncTask**

Put the `AsyncTask` in a Fragment.

Using fragments probably is the cleanest way to handle configuration changes. By default, Android destroys and recreates the fragments just like activities, however, fragments have the ability to retain their instances, simply by calling: `setRetainInstance(true)`, in one of its callback methods, for example in the `onCreate()`.

please find full implementation and description to deal with `AsyncTask`.

[Handle Android AsyncTask](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a single `AsyncTask` when nothing is already running, you can do something like:

```
if(uploadRecordings == null || uploadRecordings.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
   uploadRecordings = new UploadRecordings();
   uploadRecordings.execute(context);
}
```

This assumes that your `uploadRecordings` is a member variable. e.g.

`private UploadRecordings uploadRecordings = null;`